# Grease Pencil mask masking layers in the the wrong GP object

Tags: grease-pencil, masking

So I've got a mask in a Grease Pencil object that, besides from affecting the specific layer I've set it up to mask, it also has an effect on layers on other GP objects.....? For the layer in the same GP object as the mask, it has the desired effect - masking the place where I want the layer to be visible. For all the other layers in other GP objects, the mask excludes/hides the different layers.
The mask doesnt affect all other GP objects in the blend file, but some. I think I've read some where that the order of the different GP layers/strokes/objects are defined by the order in which they where made - as if they where "time-stamped". Can this be true..? If so, is there a way in blender to show this time creation order..?